# axios not including firebase headers on post

Tags: reactjs, firebase, axios

When I use axios to make a PATCH request with an authorization header it works fine and I can see the auth header present in the outbound request however this same method does not work for a POST. I see the auth header does not go out for a POST request, any ideas why not?

**Working**

```
 const headers = await createToken(); //firebase auth token to send to server

  let query = axios
    .patch(API_URL + path, dataObj, headers)
    .then((res) => {
      return true; // query succeeded
    })
```

**Not Working**

```
const headers = await createToken(); //firebase auth token to send to server

 let query = axios
    .post(API_URL + path, dataObj, headers)
    .then((res) => {
      return true; // query succeeded
    })
```

**Header Generation Function**

```
const createToken = async () => {
  const user = fire.auth().currentUser;
  const token = user && (await user.getIdToken());
  const payloadHeader = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };
  return payloadHeader;
};
```

However when I use this same method to make an axios

Answer (score 0):

It appears I had the following line above all the code listed that was messing with only the POST call for some reason...Commenting this out fixed the issue with POST

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; //always send cookies
```